# How can I assign value to a template only once?

Tags: c++, templates, object

Let's say I have a class as follows:

```
template <class T>
class Object {
    private:
        T object;
    public:
        Object(T object) : object(object) {}
};
```

Now within main, I want to create these objects, let's say that I prompt the user for input that specifies T. Suppose T can be an int or a char, so the output may be something like:

```
Do you want to create a char or int (c/i)?
```

Once the user specifies, I want to be able to create that object. However, I don't want to have to go through an `if...else` construct. Namely, the way that it seems this needs to be done is

```
if (answer == 'c') {
    Object(character);
} else {
    Object(int);
}
```

Obviously not exactly correct, but that's the idea. However, this gets really annoying because there are other more complicated things going on and I basically have to reconstruct this `if...else` tree every time, making the code fairly cluttered.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
type = character || int; //this would still be determined by an if..else
Object(type);
```

Comment: Template parameters are evaluated at compile time. There is no way to get them via user input really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The type of an identifier in C++ must be statically known. There is no mechanism to specify "one of a set of types" outside using class hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance and [Factory Method](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html) pattern:

```
Object* pObj = CreateObject(type);  // IntObject or CharObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Template instances, such as your `Object<char>` and `Object<int>`, are *different types*.  Templates aside, what you're doing is basically the same as trying to make a variable that can be either a `char` or an `int` depending on a user's choice at runtime.  You can't do that; the compiler needs to know the types of all variables at compile time.

You can get a similar effect using a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), or something that encapsulates one such as [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html).  Or you can create an abstract base class with virtual functions that represent the things you want to do with these values, and write derived classes that implement those virtual functions for different kinds of values.  But the approach you're trying here with templates isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Take most of your code and make it a `static` method (or methods) in a `template` class, whose type `T` is `char` or `int`.

Now do one if/else and call the static method with the right type.